# Adding items to a list in Java

Tags: java, swing, list

I must be overseeing something very simple. I just simply cant add more than 1 object to a list. I am using a jFrame made with Netbeans.
First here's my object class

```
package registros;

/**
 *
 * @author juan
 */
public class estudiantes {
 private String nombre;
 private String apellido;
 private String sexo;
 public String ci;
 private String nived;

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}
public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}
public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}
public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}
public String getCi() {
    return ci;
}
public void setCi(String ci) {
    this.ci = ci;
}
public String getNived() {
    return nived;
}
public void setNived(String nived) {
    this.nived = nived;
}
```

}

I put ci as public because when i was trying to access those values, i got an error message saying that it was set as private.

When I hit button 3, it should read the values of the jTextFields, the dadio buttons and the checkboxes (i got this working with the help of this forum, thanks guys!) But it my list only stores the last set of values it reads. What am i doing wrong? I have edited the post in order to show what i think is most relevant of the code.

```
package registros;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.*;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  // List <EST> Arreglo = new ArrayList()<EST>;
  List <estudiantes>registro;
  estudiantes es;
int a=0;
//Vector v = new Vector (5,1);
String sexoValue, nivedValue;

public NewJFrame() {
    this.registro = new ArrayList();
    this.es = new estudiantes();
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBox2 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jCheckBox3 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Registro Estudiantes");

    jLabel1.setText("Nombre");

    jLabel2.setText("Apellido");

    jLabel3.setText("C.I.");

    jLabel5.setText("Nivel de Instruccion");

    jButton1.setText("Actualizar");

    jButton2.setText("Buscar");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Insertar");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setText("Eliminar");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setText("Salir");
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
    jRadioButton1.setText("Masculino");

    buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);
    jRadioButton2.setText("Femenino");


    jTextField1.setName(""); 

    jLabel4.setText("Sexo");

    jCheckBox1.setText("Primaria");

    jCheckBox2.setText("Secundaria");

    jCheckBox3.setText("Universidad");





private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String nombreValue = jTextField1.getText();
        String apellidoValue = jTextField2.getText();
        String ciValue = jTextField3.getText();


        String nivedValue;
        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
            sexoValue ="Masculino";
        }
        else
            sexoValue = "Femenino";
        if (jCheckBox2.isSelected())
            a++;
        if (jCheckBox3.isSelected())
            a= a+2;

        if (a==0)
            nivedValue ="Primaria";
        if (a==1)
            nivedValue = "Secundaria";
            else
            nivedValue = "Universitaria";

        es.setNombre(nombreValue); 
        es.setApellido(apellidoValue);
        es.setSexo(sexoValue);
        es.setNived(nivedValue);
        es.setCi(ciValue);
        registro.add(es);
        jTextField1.setText(null);
        jTextField2.setText(null);
        jTextField3.setText(null);
        jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);
        jCheckBox2.setSelected(false);
        jCheckBox3.setSelected(false);
        jRadioButton1.setSelected(false);
        jRadioButton2.setSelected(false);
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{
      for(estudiantes est: registro){
          if (est.ci.equals(jTextField3.getText())){
    //String searchKey = jTextField3.getText();    
    //if (v.contains (searchKey)){


    jLabel6.setText(es.getNombre());
    jLabel7.setText(es.getApellido());
    jLabel8.setText(es.getCi());
    jLabel9.setText(es.getSexo());
    jLabel10.setText(es.getNived());
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox2.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox3.setSelected(false);
    jRadioButton1.setSelected(false);
    jRadioButton2.setSelected(false);
          }}
}                                        
catch (NullPointerException e){

jTextField3.setBackground(Color.red);};

}



public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don't post a wall of 400 lines of code.

Comment: Wow, it's hard to find where your problem is! Also, don't leave `catch` clauses empty; at least put a `e.printStackTrace();` so that your console prints problems you have encountered. For faster help, please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: sorry for that previous wall of code...

Comment: @CanadianDavid i just edited the post, I'm not sure it's totally SSCCE because i eliminated most of the graphical code auto generated by Netbeans. If you could take a look at it...

Comment: send summary of you code and problem!

Answer (score 1):

`estudiantes es;` is a global variable. and you initialize this in constructor. And on insert button click you insert this to list.. but on subsequent insert clicks you are just modifyin the same element and adds to list again. So as a result the list will have same element added multiple times. All with last value.

To fix this in `jButton3ActionPerformed()` method add `es = new estudiantes();` before setting values to `es` object.